# Как запретить в ListBox переключаться между элементами с помощью стрелок?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Есть `ListBox` в котором есть несколько `ListBoxItems`. Я хочу перемещать элементы с помощью стрелок (вверх, вниз, влево, вправо). Когда я добавляю один элемент, а затем его выделяю, то он замечательно перемещается, но когда несколько элементов, то получается при нажатии стрелок они перескакивают с одного элемента на другой и получается что я начинаю перемещать уже другой элемент. Каким образом можно запретить переключаться между элементами с помощью стрелок?
Прикладываю код:

```
<ListBox x:Name="drawing"
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         Background="Transparent"
         Height="{Binding HeightDrawing}"
         Width="{Binding WidthDrawing}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
         MouseLeftButtonDown="drawing_MouseLeftButtonDown"
         MouseLeftButtonUp="drawing_MouseLeftButtonUp"
         PreviewMouseWheel="drawing_MouseWheel"
         KeyDown="drawing_KeyDown"
         SelectionChanged="drawing_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:FigureTemplateSelector EllipseTemplate="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}"
                                      LineTemplate="{StaticResource LineTemplate}"
                                      RectangleTemplate="{StaticResource RectangleTemplate}" 
                                      TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Padding="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Name="Content" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                        Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код и разметку, отредактируйте вопрос. В идеале код должен быть таким, чтобы например я смог из него создать проект и проверить, что у вас там происходит. Вообще, чтобы переназначить кнопки, есть `InputBindings`, назначаете их на нужные команды, и дефолтные экшны переопределяются.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос:
Первое:
Необходимо запретить переключаться между элементами с помощью стрелок вверх, вниз, влево, вправо. Для этого нужно добавить в `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` добавить `Setter`:

```
<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="None" />
```

Второе:
Необходимо в `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` добавить `Setter` отключающий функцию `IsTabStop`:

```
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
```

Полный код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<ListBox x:Name="drawing"
                                             Grid.Row="0"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
                                             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
                                             SelectionMode="Single"
                                             Background="Transparent"
                                             Height="{Binding HeightDrawing}"
                                             Width="{Binding WidthDrawing}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
                                             MouseLeftButtonDown="drawing_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                             MouseLeftButtonUp="drawing_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                                             PreviewMouseWheel="drawing_MouseWheel"
                                             KeyDown="drawing_KeyDown"
                                             SelectionChanged="drawing_SelectionChanged">
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <Canvas />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                                            <local:FigureTemplateSelector EllipseTemplate="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}"
                                                                          LineTemplate="{StaticResource LineTemplate}"
                                                                          RectangleTemplate="{StaticResource RectangleTemplate}" 
                                                                          TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"/>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                                                        Value="{Binding X}" />
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                                                        Value="{Binding Y}" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                                            <Border Name="Border"
                                                                    BorderThickness="0.5"
                                                                    Padding="1">
                                                                <ContentPresenter Name="Content" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                                                         Value="true">
                                                                    <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                                                            Property="BorderBrush"
                                                                            Value="Transparent" />
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                                                        Value="False" />
                                                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation"
                                                        Value="None" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    </ListBox>
```

[Источник](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7e0f5db-b58f-4bba-89f8-f8690356b92a/keyboardnavigationdirectionalnavigation-property-has-no-effect-for-a-listbox?forum=wpf)